# Adding Code of Conduct to Help pulldown on top bar?

Tags: feature-request, code-of-conduct

I think that the ideal place to link the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) would be as a link below the Tour and above the Help Center on the top bar pulldown for the Help, but anywhere on that pulldown would be good.

[image]

Comment: A link in the footer would be good too.

Comment: @curiousdannii I agree, and had not thought of that, so I think you should add that as an answer.